# How to register DRF router url patterns in django 2

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My DRF routers specify a namespace so that I can `reverse` my urls:

**urls.py:**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('widget/', MyWidgetViewSet, base_name='widgets')
urlpatterns =+ [
    url(r'/path/to/API/', include(router.urls, namespace='widget-api'),
]
```

Which, when upgrading to django 2, gives:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.

Django 2 [now requires](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs) `app_name` if the `namespace` kwarg is specified when using `include`. What's the right way to specify `app_name` when the url patterns are constructed by a DRF url router? I don't think [the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#using-include-with-routers) is up-to-date for django 2 on this subject.

Comment: Hi, good point, could you open [an issue](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues) please ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just that the documentation hasn't caught up with django 2 and I just need to change my syntax a bit, or if the router is unable to produce the url patterns in the required format.

Comment: did you try to use `path` instead of `ùrl`

Comment: Yeah, the issue is there with `path` and `url`.

Comment: no, the issue is with `namespace`.

Answer (score 10):

You need to put `app_name = 'x'` in your application's `url.py` file. This is a little buried in the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#id5

For example, if in `/project/project/urls.py` you have:

```
path('', include('app.urls', namespace='app'))
```

Then in the corresponding url file (in `/project/app/urls.py`) you need to specify the `app_name` parameter with:

```
app_name = 'app'  #the weird code
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'), #this can be anything
]
```

Comment: Actually, that's not the fix (even though yes you specify the `app_name` param in django that way). Django 2 now expects the namespace to be provided when using `include` and DRF 3.7.x doesn't do that. The fix is to be included in 3.8.0.

Comment: After posting this I started to wonder about that. Maybe it will be helpful if you create a new answer. I will delete or edit this one (or you can edit it, but it might be good for you to get credit and just make a new answer we can upvote).

Comment: I probably will create a new answer when 3.8 comes out. For the moment, there's no answer other than to avoid namespacing your viewsets.

Comment: Yes, but for now that is the right answer, no? Seems worth putting it as a standalone answer.

Comment: Also, check what kind of class your viewset is inheriting, if you're some model based class use something like `class MyWidgetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):` since `views.ViewSet` don't have actions

Comment: Does this mean we can't use DRF reverse with Django 2.x until DRF next version is released? Since we can't use reverse without namespaces and can't use namespaces without app_name and DRF doesn't yet support app_name?

Comment: What if the app is not yours? I can copy / paste urls.py from that app... But the app (drf-tus) also registers urls like `router = TusAPIRouter() ... urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include(router.urls, namespace='api'))`. And even in this code I got the same error (**ImproperlyConfigured**).

Answer (score 1):

It's just necessary to use '{basename}-list' in reverse function.
In your case, it's going to be:  `reverse('widgets-list')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the router.urls as a tuple and add the app name to the tuple instead of only include router.urls

According to your example you should try with something like:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('widget/', MyWidgetViewSet, base_name='widgets')
urlpatterns =+ [
    url(r'/path/to/API/', include((router.urls, 'my_app_name'), namespace='widget-api'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'widget/', MyWidgetViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^path/to/API/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='widget-api'))
]
```

See http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/tutorial/quickstart#urls