# Django 2.0 | include multiple urls conf namespace

Tags: python, django, namespaces

This "problem" is quite related to : [django 2.0 url.py include namespace="xyz"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48063790/django-2-0-url-py-include-namespace-xyz)

The previous dev used Django 1.9 (or maybe even before) but we are now migrating to Django 2.0.
We got 3 sites on the same project, all with only 1 specific URLS Conf

```
### MAIN PROJECT REFERENCING ALL SITES ###
###         Nothing changed here       ###
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path
from frontend import urls as frontend_urls
from search import urls as search_urls
from international import urls as international_urls

# Customisation admin
admin.site.site_header = 'INT - ADMIN'

temppatterns = [   
# Admin Sites
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
# Organisation Sites
url(r'^frontend/', include(frontend_urls)),
# 1st Platform
url(r'^search/', include(search_urls)),
# 2nd Platform
url(r'^international/', include(international_urls)),
]
urlpatterns = temppatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here is the previous frontend URLs CONF

```
FRONTEND_PATTERNS = [
    url(r'^conseiller$', views.GuidanceView.as_view(), name='guidance'),
    .......
    url(r'^contact$', views.ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'),
    url(r'^$', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
]

COMPANY_PATTERNS = [
    url(r'^companydetail/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.MemberLgView.as_view(),
        name='lg-detail'),
    url(r'^asso/orga/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.MemberOrgView.as_view(),
        name='org-detail'),
]

CONTENT_PATTERNS = [
    .......
]

EVENT_PATTERNS = [
    .......
]

REDIRECT_PATTERNS = [
    url(r'^actualite/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.OldBlogRedirectView.as_view(),
        name='blog-redirect'),
    .......
    url(r'^ressources$',
        RedirectView.as_view(
            url=reverse_lazy('frontend:doc'), permanent=True)),
]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(FRONTEND_PATTERNS, namespace='frontend')),
    url(r'^', include(COMPANY_PATTERNS, namespace='companies')),
    url(r'^', include(CONTENT_PATTERNS, namespace='contents')),
    url(r'^', include(REDIRECT_PATTERNS, namespace='redirects')),
    url(r'^', include(EVENT_PATTERNS, namespace='events')),
] + static(
    settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

But now, the include with namespace seems to be deprecated. So we changed few things in this docs

```
# Added app_name
app_name="frontend"

# Deleting namespace - deprecated
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^', include(FRONTEND_PATTERNS)),
    re_path(r'^', include(COMPANY_PATTERNS)),
    re_path(r'^', include(CONTENT_PATTERNS)),
    re_path(r'^', include(REDIRECT_PATTERNS)),
    re_path(r'^', include(EVENT_PATTERNS)),
] + static(
    settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

But now we got this error at 127.0.0.1:8000/frontend :

> NoReverseMatch at /frontend/ 'companies' is not a registered namespace

on

> ```
> 'companies:%s-detail' % self.route_name, args=(self.slug, ))
> ```

Which is logic. So I tried to configure URLs like this

> ```
> re_path(r'^', include(COMPANY_PATTERNS, namespace='companies')),
> ```

But got

> ```
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.
> ```

Reading the doc, it appears I should use

> ```
> re_path(r'^', include((COMPANY_PATTERNS, app_name), namespace='companies')),
> ```

So let's go, but we are back to this :

> NoReverseMatch at /frontend/ 'companies' is not a registered namespace

So I sat and tried to add frontend: before companies which work !

> ```
> 'frontend:companies:%s-detail' % self.route_name, args=(self.slug, ))
> ```

However, this is a really big big work of refactorisation, is there a better way to include URLs and set a dedicated namespace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the namespace to the pattern lists?

```
REDIRECT_PATTERNS = ( [
        url(r'^actualite/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
            views.OldBlogRedirectView.as_view(),
            name='blog-redirect'),
        .......
        url(r'^ressources$',
            RedirectView.as_view(
                url=reverse_lazy('frontend:doc'), permanent=True)),
    ] , 'redirects') 

...

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^', include(REDIRECT_PATTERNS)),
    ...
```

I assume, this is what your first `ImproperlyConfigured` exception complains about.
There is another way (shown here in the answer of py_dude); both are explained in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs).

Answer (score 1):

For Django 2.0 this should look like:

```
temppatterns = [   
# Admin Sites
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
# Organisation Sites
path('frontend/', include('frontend.urls')),
# 1st Platform
path('search/', include('search.urls')),
# 2nd Platform
path('international/', include('international.urls')),
]
```

And so on...
Look at `url()` functions are replaced with `path()` and `regexp strings` replaced with `strings`

Did you read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)?

Also, see the `include()` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#include) to know, what object could be passed to this function

Comment: It should yeah. btw re_path() replace url(), they are not the same as path()