# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apps'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I'm using Django 1.9 and DRF 3.9.2 in my project. In my urls.py I've used this code

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include('apps.rest_slack.urls', namespace='rest_slack')),
]
```

and I've set a router in my rest_slack-urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_slack.views import DRSEventView, DRSCommandView

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'web', DRSEventView)
router.register(r'events', DRSCommandView)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

when I try to run server its giving me ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apps' error. please tell what changes I can do?

```
myproject/
 |-- slack/
 |    |-- rest_slack/                
 |    |    |-- migrations/
 |    |    |    +-- __init__.py
 |    |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |    |-- admin.py
 |    |    |-- apps.py
 |    |    |-- models.py
 |    |    |-- tests.py
 |    |    |-- urls.py
 |    |    +-- views.py
 |    |-- slack/
 |    |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |    |-- settings.py
 |    |    |-- urls.py
 |    |    |-- wsgi.py
 |    +-- manage.py
 +-- venv/
```

Comment: What is your folder structure?

Comment: Is it related to that? @AdamBarnes

Comment: Very much so!  When you pass a dotted string as the first argument to `include()`, it tries to import that path.  If `import apps.rest_slack.urls` won't work, your `include()` won't either.  To determine the correct string to use, a look at your folder structure would be necessary.

Comment: Can you tell me how do I see it through a command prompt in mac? @AdamBarnes

Comment: I've updated it, please check. @AdamBarnes

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

When you pass a dotted string as the first argument to `include()`, it tries to import that path.  If `import apps.rest_slack.urls` won't work, your `include()` won't either.

From the looks of your folder structure, it seems you would need to use `include('rest_slack.urls', ...)`.

To confirm if this is the case, you could run `import rest_slack.urls` in `./manage.py shell`, or simply make the change in your `slack/urls.py` and see if it works.

Comment: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'rest_slack.urls' from '/Users/sid/webhooksub/slack/rest_slack/urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Comment: Now when I try to run server I'm getting this error

Comment: It seems like it might be an [issue with DRF](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2760) and using a namespace in `include()`?  Try removing the namespace from your `include()` call, but if that doesn't work, I would recommend opening another question, as your original issue is now solved.

Comment: Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47654342/how-to-register-drf-router-url-patterns-in-django-2) question out - it may be related.

Answer (score 0):

From your project structure it looks as though your urls should be configured like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include('slack.rest_slack.urls', namespace='rest_slack')),
]
```

or if that doesn't work try:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include('myproject.slack.rest_slack.urls', namespace='rest_slack')),
]
```

Your project structure goes `myproject.slack.rest_slack.urls.py`. I don't see an apps folder in there anywhere.